# systemd-nspawn inside lxc container

Tags: centos, chroot, lxc, systemd-nspawn

I've a nice chroot environment built with centos 7. I start it using systemd-nspawn.
Everything works correctly in my local machine and in all the servers I've seen until now.
Today I was asked to put this chroot in a new server, I copied the folder as usual, but when I started it with "systemd-nspawn -D chroot-folder -b" I got:

```
Spawning container chroot-folder on /opt/chroot-folder.
Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
Container chroot-folder failed with error code 1.
```

This new server is not a physical server, it's a lxc container with installed centos 7.
I don't know what informations I can provide to debug the issue.
Everything I found on google didn't work. So here I am..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and did some tests, I didn't notice any issue, so I consider it safe (at least for my scenario):
what I've done is change "lxc.mount.auto" in "/usr/local/share/lxc/config/common.conf" and remove "cgroup:mixed".